# How to use alert box without redirecting to a different page in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to show a custom alert box to make sure the user want to delete an item. After deleting that item, a new alert box opens and says "the item is deleted", then the user must click OK button.

My problem is, after deleting the item, the page is redirects to a different page without clicking OK button. How can I arrange the code to achieve my point.

The controller;

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
   Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
   db.Categories.Remove(category);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The delete button;

```
<button type="button" class="btn bg-red waves-effect" onclick="Delete();">Delete</button>
```

The alert script;

```
<script>
    function Delete()
    {
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        },
            function () {
                location.href = '@Url.Action("Delete", "Categories", new { id = Model.Id })',
                swal({
                    title: "Deleted!",
                    text: "Your imaginary file has been deleted.",
                    type: "success"
                })
            });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the line  `location.href="Categories/Delete/123"`, the browser basically redirects the current page to this new url, essentially making a new GET request. If you want to simply delete the item from server and show an alert to user, you want to do it via ajax.

So in the "Confirm delete" button click's callback, make an ajax call to server. You may use jQuery `$.post` method.

```
function Delete() {
    swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        },
        function() {
            var url = '@Url.Action("Delete", "Home", new {id = Model.Id})';
            $.post(url,
                function(response) {
                    if (response.success === "success") {
                        swal({
                            title: "Deleted!",
                            text: "Your imaginary file has been deleted.",
                            type: "success"
                        });
                    } else {
                        // failed to delete. show messaage to user
                        alert(response.message);
                    }
                });
        });
}
```

Also since you are making the Delete method call via ajax, You may return a json response instead of a redirect response. I would also recommend keeping the Delete action an HttpPost action as it changes data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
   try
   {
     Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
     db.Categories.Remove(category);
     db.SaveChanges();
     if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
     {
       return Json(new { status  = "success" });
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
     return Json(new { status = "failed",message=e.Message });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think the answer was jQuery. The problem is solved now.